# Change Document Root for existing site - IspConfig 3

Tags: ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I don't find a solution for the following problem.

I have lot of website into /var/www folder, now i want change the webpath for /home/sites folder.

I change into IspConfig Server Config :
[image]

But it's didn't work, can you help me with a real instruction for move all existing site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing that for existing sites is not supported.